# Logic Expressions and Notation

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am brand new to logic so am trying to teach myself how to write logic expressions. Let's say I take the following Modal ontological argument:

-Premise 1: It is possible that God exists.
-Premise 2: If it is possible that God exits, then God exists in some possible worlds.
-Premise 3:If God exists in some possible worlds, then God exists in All possible worlds.

-Premise 4: If God exists in all Possible Worlds,then God exists in the actual world.

-Premise 5: If God exists in the actual world, then God exists

or the summary of that argument....

-Premise 1: It is at least possible (◊) for God to exist

-Premise 2: If God’s existence is possible, then necessarily (□), God does exist

-Premise 3: Therefore it follows (⊨), necessarily (□), God exists (∃)

In terms of notation what is the best and simplest way to express the premises and argument where P denotes God?

◊P → □P ⊨ ∃P

I know this is most likely wrong so any help much appreciated

Comment: Maybe: **◊∃P, ◊P → □P ⊨ ∃P**... But syntax of Modal Logic is slightly different: we have to quantify individuals and not propositions. Thus, **◊∃xGod(x)** to mean "It is possible that God exists**.

Comment: Thanks Mauro ALLEGRANZA that this VERY helpful. I hadn't even appreciated why modal logic was required in this example, but now I think I do, as it is attempting to quantify the truth of the judgement in terms of possibility. necessity or impossibility

Comment: Also apart from notation that argument is just bad. Like it's undefined what god is, what a "possible world" is. Premise 3 is just wrong as it literally gives no reason why that should follow and the reason given to not entail that conclusion. Premise 4 and 5 follow from Premise 3 which makes these steps ok but only because 3 was so dead wrong. And also the possibility of something to exist does not entail it's existence. So maybe things get clearer if you look for examples that actually work.

Comment: @haxor789 I wasn't actually concerned with the argument itself I was using it as an example since it was recently shared on here.  For what it's worth, I don't understand Premise 3 either, as it does not seem to necessarily follow. I can only think that it means if God is necessary and exists in one possible world then be necessity he would exit in ALL possible worlds.

Comment: @Teddy so you are basically saying that if god is necessary, he/she exists ….

Comment: @Oбжорoв well it isn't me saying that, but it is one of the premise of the ontological argument, yes. Whether the argument has any validity, I have no idea. I was using it to learn logic

Comment: As a side comment, 2, 4, and 5, look like they should be inferable from the logic and so should not be called premises. It depends, of course, on what logic you are using, but just from general principles, only 1 and 3 look like proper premises.

Comment: @haxor789, there are a lot of philosophers, both theistic and atheistic who would agree with premise 3: If God exists possibly, then he exists necessarily, or a slight variation: God either necessarily exists or necessarily does not exist.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Even after contemplating that idea and trying to look up the definition I'm none the wiser how that should work. I mean if possible existence entailed necessary existence wouldn't that make the entire possible/necessary distinction obsolete? Like necessity requires for it to not possibly not exist, but an atheist could just imagine a possible world without god and if just one of that could possibly exist it would not necessarily exist, right?

Comment: @haxor789 I think the argument hinges on the definition of God being what William LaneCraig calls 'A maximally great being' a characteristic of which is necessity. Atheists have replaced God with a unicorn to disprove the argument, but a theist rebuttal would be that a unicorn is not a maximally great being, therefore not necessary. This is my understanding of the argument, although admittedly I haven't looked into it deeply, I was just trying to figure out the notation

Comment: @Teddy But that would be begging the question, like sure if you define god to be necessary and necessity requires existences then god exists, but not because he/she/it does, but just because you defined it that way, yet there's no argument for that assertion. Also it would need further assumptions on god not given in the argument, which makes it formally dubious, regardless of whether one agrees or disagrees with the conclusion. It's not really relevant to notation but maybe it still helps to pick an example where the logic is easier to follow and not a distractor of it it's own ;)

Comment: @haxor789 I think (again I am new to this) it is not that proponents of the argument (which I believe has been well refuted) are starting by defining God has necessary, they are saying the already accepted definition of God being all knowing, all powerful etc requires that he is necessary, and if he is necessary he must exist in some possible worlds etc etc. Perhaps others more familiar with the argument can help. I take your point, I should have perhaps started with an easier argument to express lol

Comment: You can see [Gödel's ontological proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof): the attempted proof by the greatest 20th Century logician.

Comment: @haxor789, you might find the SEP article interesting: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/god-necessary-being/

Comment: @DavidGudeman So they are essentially referring to things that are necessary, such as abstract objects which do exist in all possible worlds and then argue that these are grounded in god and therefore a proof of their existence is a proof of the existence of god as god is necessary for their existence? But that's still begging the question if god IS necessary for their existence. Or if this would refer to A "god" that might be different in concept from what was initially claimed also it doesn't provide a reason for why possibility leads to necessity, right?

Comment: @haxor789 First, the definition of terms in an argument is irrelevant to its validity. Logic is topic-neutral. Second, it is not necessary to define an argument's terms to accept its premises. For example, it is not necessary to define "electron" to accept the premise "electrons have negative charge". Third, it makes no sense to say that a premise is "wrong" *because* it lacks justification. That's what a premise is.

Comment: @user76284 I didn't question the validity, did I? Yes this seems to be a chain of valid arguments it's just weird that the first premise has an unknown truth value and any subsequent premise is an implication that almost defies what the logical operator of an implication is supposed to be. Existence does not follow from possibility and necessity NOT from existence and so on. So already the 2nd premise is obviously false so it's weird to keep stacking arguments on top of it. The only way in which it could not be false is if there are non-standard definitions used but they not to be mentioned.

Comment: @haxor789 The 2nd premise is true by definition in standard modal semantics.

Comment: @user76284 In my initial comment I wasn't aware of the technical definitions of modal logic and so these statements seemed as if something was missing from them. Some semantic definitions for some of these words, without which they don't make much sense. And apparently I wasn't far off questioning what a "possible world" is and expecting a reasoning that is absent in this argument. Now I know that for people familiar with modal logic there are those semantic models which give these premises meaning. That being said even with those models premise 3 is somewhat of a stretch...